# How do you make sense of this coding question?

Tags: function

I have been given a coding question to answer, however I'm unable to make sense of it:

**Consider a sequence of integers A1, A2, ... for which An = A(n-1) + A(n-2) for all n > 2. You are given the first two elements of the sequence A1 and A2, and the index n.
Write a function to output the n-th element of the sequence. The function will take a single argument consisting of a single string which contains integers A1, A2 and n separated by single spaces.**

While I'm not looking for anyone to give me the answer, could anyone break this down or explain it to me as a starting point?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that what they mean is that n is the value of A in the array. For example, say you are trying to find A1, I would say in this case n=1 and therefore plugging in the equation that would be A1=A(1-1) + A(1-2). This is a very confusing equation and I hope my answer helps